# SQL create next numerical number automatically

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to insert data into my table but want each entry to have an id that is not already taken.

For example:

```
INSERT INTO Table_lol (id, name, email, phone, address)
VALUES (1, bob, boblol@example.com, 1111111, 123 lollane);
```

I could add something like `WHERE NOT EXISTS` but that only prevents the id from being overwritten. I don't want the user to have to make an id, I want it to generate the next number so the user can't mess anything up.

Is this possible to do? Thanks!

Comment: [`id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html) and insert without specifying `id` column

Answer (score 2):

Use auto_increment when you create the table 
Ex:

```
CREATE TABLE animals ( 
     id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
     name CHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
     PRIMARY KEY (id) );
```

Then don't write the value you want for the id
Ex:

```
INSERT INTO Table_lol (name, email, phone, address)
VALUES (bob, boblol@example.com, 1111111, 123 lollane);
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a new table, then I would create the `id` field with an identity column which would automatically manage the id's in the field.

If this is an existing table, then try using:

```
INSERT INTO Table_lol(id, name, email, phone, address)
    SELECT MAX(id) + 1, 'bob', 'boblol@example.com', 1111111, 123 lollane
    FROM Table_lol;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have your table made and cant use auto-increment as mentioned in the other answer/comments, you could select the Max value of the id column and add 1 to it.

```
$max = SELECT MAX( id ) FROM Table_lol;
INSERT INTO Table_lol( customer_id, firstname, surname )
VALUES ($max+1 ,bob, boblol@example.com, 1111111, 123 lollane)
```